# Mysql node.js intermittent connectivity issue

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

In my node.js app I am using the mysql library for database connectivity.

When I start my node server I can query the database perfectly fine – no issues

When I query the database after 5 minutes the server returns the following error:

```
{"code":"PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR","fatal":false}
```

If I restart my node.js server I can query again with no issues…

Here is my code

```
const mysql = require('mysql');


let connection = mysql.createPool({
  host: config.mysql.host,
  user: config.mysql.user,
  password: config.mysql.password,
  database: config.mysql.database
});


router.post('/subscription', (req, res) => {
  const user = req.body;
  const q = 'INSERT into Subscription SET ?';
  connection.query(q, user, (err, results) => {
    if (err)
      return res.json(err);
    return res.json(results);
  });
});
```

I have used both mysql.createConnection and mysql.createPool…. also tried ending the connection manually with connection.end….

Both results end in the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a connection from the pool and use that, not query the pool itself. When you get a connection from the pool, the pool will make sure you get a valid connection from the pool. So your code would be:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');


let pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: config.mysql.host,
  user: config.mysql.user,
  password: config.mysql.password,
  database: config.mysql.database
});


router.post('/subscription', (req, res) => {
  const user = req.body;
  const q = 'INSERT into Subscription SET ?';
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
     if (err)
       return res.json(err);

     connection.query(q, user, (err, results) => {
       if (err)
         return res.json(err);
       return res.json(results);
     });
  })
});
```

**UPDATE**:

You don't need to do separate pool.getConnection and connection.query, you can combine them into a pool.query which will get a connection, do the query and release the connection. So, the updated code would be:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

let pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: config.mysql.host,
  user: config.mysql.user,
  password: config.mysql.password,
  database: config.mysql.database
});


router.post('/subscription', (req, res) => {
  const user = req.body;
  const q = 'INSERT into Subscription SET ?';
  pool.query(q, user, function(err, connection) {
     if (err)
       return res.json(err);

     return res.json(results);
  });
});
```

Comment: I probably should have put the releaseConnection in there somewhere